# On-screen keyboard resizes app when an input box is selected Apache Cordova Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio, cordova

I am trying to develop an app with the Apache Cordova tools for Visual Studio and i believed i had finished the project until I started using it on a device and the on-screen keyboard re-sized the entire app when it popped up.  The application looks the way i would like it to until the user selects an input box and the on-screen keyboard pops up, which then makes the screen shrink to compensate for the keyboard.

How can I make it so that the keyboard just overlaps the layout already present instead of re-sizing it and making a new one?  I can't seem to find any solutions on the internet so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you testing on an Android device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dustin - you need to use the Keyboard plug-in to help customize this behavior. You can find the plug-in at NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-keyboard

The exact line of code that will give you what you want is:

```
Keyboard.shrinkView(false);
```

Cheers,

Kirupa

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I don't know if you have any experience using this plugin but if so, when would you make this call? only one time in the onLoad method in your JS file or in every function that deals with input?

Comment: Just one time when using the plugin. I've used it after the onLoad method, and it worked just fine! :-)